# jQuery, script doesn't recognize newly appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a short script that styles form radio buttons. Check working example http://jsfiddle.net/YJRsk/.

This works great when radio buttons already exist in DOM. So when page load, they get styled properly.

The problem is when i add radio buttons dynamically by appending them, the script doesn't recognize them since it already ran on page load. So for that reason i get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. How can i work around this so that newly appended radios gets automatically styled on the spot without having to save and refresh the page. I tried to running the script after each radio append, but that didn't work.

```
var item = '<li><input type="radio" value="'+uniqid()+'" class="styled" name="test"/><label class="radioButton">Radio button</label></li>';
$('button').live('click', function() {
    $(item).appendTo('#radio');
})
```

Check the jsfiddle example and click the "add radio" button to test.

Comment: The problem lies with your *custom_form.js*. Which only runs on load, and not after adding to the dom.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to re-run that js file after each append so newly appended elements gets styled

Comment: You could, by simple adding `Custom.init();` to the onclick handler. But as expected this will be correct for new elements only and break already *re-formated* ones badly. My best advice would be to dump that whole script and redo it with jQuery only.

Answer (score 3):

Use a CSS rule and add a class to all radio buttons. If you are using advanced jQuery selectors for styling, I'd recommend simply applying that styling function on creation of each new element.

Edit: The basic problem here is that your .js files are loaded on page load, so if you use something like:

```
$(".mybutton").click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

This event will only be 'tacked onto' .mybutton elements that exist at page load. If you create/add elements dynamically, you will have to assign the above event handler to them again.

This also has the effect that your `uniqid()` function will be creating the same id for all radio buttons added currently. Do it like this instead:

```
$('button').live('click', function() {
    var item = '<li><input type="radio" value="'+uniqid()+'" class="styled" name="test"/><label class="radioButton">Radio button</label></li>';
    $(item).appendTo('#radio');
})
```

Edit 2:

I don't know what jQuery styling you are using for your radio button, but the basic idea is to use the styling function on your newly created button each time. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YJRsk/11/

If I am still missing something, please elaborate and show us the jQuery you use for radio button styling.

Comment: You are right about unique. it should be inside the click function  +1. But your answer still doesn't solve my issue. I'm trying to find a way to run the radio script after each append so we get a functional radio button on all newly added radios

Comment: Of course it isn't working, since the jQuery function I made is just a mockup. As you haven't showed us the actual jQuery/JavaScript code you want to use for all your radio buttons, it's hard to get it to work properly. Like I said - if I am missing something, please try to elaborate your original post to make the problem and all factors clearer.

Comment: The js file is in jsfiddle. Look at your left side menu manage resources. The file is called custom_form.js

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm assuming this is a pre-packaged solution that you haven't made yourself? In that case I think it's fair to say that you'll have to use it as it was designed, and it doesn't look like it's meant to be used for dynamically added buttons (but I could be wrong entirely). I'm sorry, but this is a bit to contrived for me to assist you with any further.

Comment: I understand, but i'm still looking for a way to re-run that js file after each append so elements get styled. I don't see why this can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum number of radio buttons, this is what I would do:

1. Add maximum number of radio buttons to the form (show just those which you wan't to be shown at the beginning)
2. Leave a script to style them
3. On button click, just show already styled radio buttons one by one

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to hide additional buttons after script have styled them... Try and you'll see...

Comment: I thought about this as well and I agree that this is the best solution. Rerunning the entire script seems like a waste, and could probably cause some problems either way.

Comment: The script is not written to be called more than once on the same page. I mean, it doesn't even work that way. You can try it. Just call `Custom.init();`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a piece of your HTML code in the Javascript.

```
var item = '<li><span class="radio" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt;"></span><input type="radio" value="'+uniqid()+'" class="styled" name="test"/><label class="radioButton">Radio button</label></li>';

$('button').live('click', function() {
    $(item).appendTo('#radio');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YJRsk/3/

That said, it's probably a smarter idea to style your radio buttons using CSS

Comment: Thanks, i was aware of this, but that doesn't make the button functional. My question was how can we run the script again after appending so we get a functional radio button.

Comment: Use jQuery's `live` function.

Comment: And would you consider using CSS for styling the radio buttons?

Comment: You can't style radios with pure css and maintain cross browser support. But i'm open to see what you have.