# HTML elements loaded after page load not recognized by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had this issue with two different projects and finally realized what it could have been on this most recent one. In both, I'm pulling in some dynamic text and a dynamically-valued button from SQL (in one project through a Python MVC, in the other through PHP), and I have an onclick function on the button that hides some of the text.

The issue that it works the second time I try it, perfectly fine. With this second project, I finally put a few alerts in the right places and realized that on the first click, the visibility/display CSS attribute has no value (not undefined, when I alert(object.style.display) it's just blank). I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877145/jquery-script-doesnt-recognize-newly-appended-elements) issue may be my answer, but with .live() depreciated in jQuery, I'm not exactly sure what to do with .on() - is the event I'm looking for load, or is there something else I should use?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I'm not exactly sure what to do with .on()" Read documentation, thats what you have to do

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegation:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '[selector for dynamic elements]', function () {
    // Do stuff here
} );
```

This way the handler is bound to an element that is always present on the page, and the `selector` parameter allows you to specify the dynamic elements you want to manipulate.

**UPDATE**

Given the code sample in your comment below, assuming `thing1` is static and `thing2` is dynamic, then you would have something like this:

```
$( '#thing1' ).on( 'click', '#thing2', function () {
    // Do stuff here (your foo() function code)
} );
```

Or you could refer to a named function as well:

```
$( '#thing1' ).on( 'click', '#thing2', foo /* name of function to assign to event */ );
```

Comment: Only note I'd add, is that if you have a static parent that isn't as high up in the DOM as the `document`, it is recommended to bind to that instead. otherwise, +1

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, instead of...
`<div id="thing1">
  <div id="thing2" onclick="foo()">
  </div>
</div>`

...it will be...
`$(document | thing1).on('click', 'thing2', function(foo){...

...

<div id="thing1">
  <div id="thing2">
  </div>
</div>`
...if thing1 is static and thing2 is dynamic?

NB: line breaks do not work. got it.

Comment: @ahwitz I responded above in my answer to take advantage of the formatting.